# Understanding Sum(1) sum(2) sum(3)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum, aggregate-functions

Consider a table below having one column having 10 records.
I am not able to understand how

```
SUM(1) gives output 10
SUM(2) gives output 20
SUM(3) gives output 30

create table test_a4(idCol numeric);
insert into test_a4(idCol) values (1),(2),  (3),  (4), (5) , (6), (7), (8), (9) , (10)
Select SUM(1) FROM test_a4 -- SUM(1) gives output 10
Select SUM(2) FROM test_a4 -- SUM(2) gives output 20
Select SUM(3) FROM test_a4 -- SUM(3) gives output 30
```

Comment: You are summing a literal number, once per row. So multiplying the number in your sum by 10. i.e. sum(3) = 3 * 10. What did you expect it to do?

Answer (score 6):

Well, `sum(1)` does just what it says: `sum()` fixed integer value `1` across all rows in the table. You have 10 rows, so this produces `10` - in other words this is `1 * 10`.

Same logic turns `sum(2)` to `20` (that's `2 * 10`), and so on.

To say the least, it is quite unclear what the actual intent of this query is.

Answer (score 4):

Hmmm . . . How can I explain this?  Let's use fewer rows.  You have a table:

```
id
 1
 2
 3
```

Then when you do:

```
select sum(10)
from t
```

it is really calculating:

```
id      num
 1       10
 2       10
 3       10
```

Hence, you get `30`.  That is, the "constant" is applied to every row being summed.